# How does APCluster handle NA values in the similarity matrix?

Tags: r

I am using APCluster to cluster a set of data points. The similarity matrix, generated from a correlation matrix, has several "NA" values.
Does APCluster tolerate "NA" in the similarity matrix or does it croak?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APCluster can handle NAs in the similarity matrix without crashing. Actually, NAs are explicitly replaced by -realmax, which means they are treated as maximum dissimilarity. I am saying this with the assumption that you are referring to the R package that I am maintaining. If your question relates to any other AP implementation, my answer does not necessarily apply.

Comment: Thanks  UBod, will try this out.